# How to color-code the positive and negative bars in barplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data:

```
df
    rowname   repo
1   revrepo  0.888
2  bankrate  0.402
3       CRR  0.250
4  Callrate  0.723
5       WPI  0.049
6       GDP -0.318
7       FED  0.110
8     width  0.209
9       nse  0.059
10      usd  0.185
```

I am plotting the barplot as shown below:

```
df %>% mutate(rowname = factor(rowname, levels = rowname[order(repo)])) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = rowname, y = repo)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
ylab("Correlation with repo") +
xlab("Independent Variable")
```

I get the following plot:
[image: ggplot bar plot]

I would like to color the negative bars as red and all positive bars as grey.

Comment: `geom_bar(aes(fill = repo < 0), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE,
                    breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE), 
                    values=c("gray", "red"))`

Comment: Fantastic.Worked liked a charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing Andrey Kolyadin comment as a solution to make it stop it appearing as a question unanswered:

```
geom_bar(aes(fill = repo < 0), stat = "identity") + scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE, breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE), values=c("gray", "red"))
```